# Run Python Tensor Flow application from .net MVC (No iron python and python.exe solutions)

Tags: c#, python, .net, asp.net-mvc, tensorflow

I  am trying to deploy my LSTM model in python script on .net MVC application. I can't use following options from C#

1. Iron Python: Doesn't supports pandas, numpy and several other libraries.
2. Creating a process using python.exe: I can't use this option due to security reasons on client-server web application.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would reevaluate starting a python.exe process. When I did a similar thing with [BillionSongs](https://github.com/losttech/BillionSongs) I ended up starting a separate process because otherwise it was impossible to make output reproducible (which might not be important for your model: I used GPT-2 and it has some form of output randomization). It is also better if you need to parallelize inference which otherwise would be obstructed due to Python's GIL.

If for some reason external process is not an option, [Python.NET](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet) will let you run Python in-process.

Alternatively, you can use a commercial solution such as [Gradient](https://losttech.software/gradient.html), which will also run Python in-process, additionally providing strongly-typed bindings for TensorFlow and a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LostTech.TensorFlow.Python) to simplify deployment. But it is currently in preview, with release sometime this spring.